# Making a HTML request without dart:html

Tags: dart

I'd like to use the static `HttpRequest.getString` method in a console application. However when importing `dart:html` to do this I get the following error "The built-in library 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM". I understand why, but I'm not sure what the alternative is since I'm very new to the language.

So my question is how do I make a `HttpRequest` without the `dart:html` library?

As always, any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [HttpClient](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_io/HttpClient.html) from *dart:io* library.

Comment: There is also the [http package](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16937319/1460491), which is a bit simpler to use.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `http` package. It has a much nicer API for making HTTP requests than `HttpClient`. Here is a simple GET request using `http`:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  var url = 'http://httpbin.org/';
  http.get(url).then((response) {
    print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
    print("Response body: ${response.body}");
  });
}
```

Or even more simply:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  http.read("http://httpbin.org/").then(print);
}
```

More examples at:

https://github.com/dart-lang/code_snippets/tree/master/recipes/dart_io/pkg_http/bin